# How do I save data to firebase using a randomID?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wish to replace the words "one" that is highlighted in yellow with random IDs generated by firebase the same way my child nodes are randomly generated IDs using the push method.
[image: I hope this picture can better explain my question.]

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference Med_History = database.getReference("Patient_Medication_History");

Med_History.child(SignInIC.CustomUID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        String taken = "Taken";
        String date = formattedDate.toString();
        String time = formattedTime.toString();
        String status = taken.toString();
        String medication = TV.getText().toString();
        String month = formattedMonth.toString();

        String combined = medication + " - " + status + " at " + time + " on " + date;
        String one = combined;

        Medication_History medication_history = new Medication_History(one);
        Med_History.child(SignInIC.CustomUID).child(month).setValue(medication_history);

        Intent Register_SignIn = new Intent(Medication_Attendance.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(Register_SignIn);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
public class Medication_History {

    private String One;

    public Medication_History() {
    }

    public Medication_History(String one) {
        One = one;
    }

    public String getOne() { return One; }

    public void setOne(String one) { One = one; }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you currently generate that database structure? That will make it much easier to show you what to do.

Comment: Please don't post images of code (or other textual content). Instead paste the actual code, and use the formatting tools that Stack Overflow provides to highlight it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Im not sure why the first and last line of my code for my class is being excluded though

Comment: You need to indent the entire block. Cmd/Ctrl-K is your friend on such edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a dynamic key in a Java class (so-called POJO) that you're writing to the database. But you can easily use a dynamic key when just writing the primitive string value:

```
String combined = medication + " - " + status + " at " + time + " on " +` date;
String key = Med_History().push().getKey();
Med_History.child(SignInIC.CustomUID).child(key).setValue(combined);
```

The trick here is that `push()` is a pure client-side operation, so you can safely call it to generate an ID that you use elsewhere.

Btw, the above has the same result as the slightly more idiomatic:

```
String combined = medication + " - " + status + " at " + time + " on " +` date;
Med_History.child(SignInIC.CustomUID).push().setValue(combined);
```

Comment: Your idea actually is much simpler! and i can achieve the results i want with just 1 click..I would actually like to accept both Peter's and your answer but i cant and your answer was better..Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Nov");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             String key=ds.getKey();
             String value=ds.child("one").getValue().toString();
             ref.child(key).push().setValue(value);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
  });
```

Here you retrieve the random id using the `getKey()`, then you retrieve the values of child node `one` and then you add the value of the random id `key` inside the `child()`, use the `push()` method to generate another random id, and set the value.

Comment: I have tried that and it still saves my data as 
"one" : "Fondaparinux (2.5mg/0.5ml) - Taken at 03:03:12 on 10-Nov-2018"
Is there any way to replace "one" with a random ID such as the way i saved my child using the push() method?

Comment: @JoelHong This code is pretty close and what it does is read the value of an existing *one* node and write that value out to another node with a 'random' key. However, it's missing one step; the old *one* node needs to to be removed.

Comment: Wow..thanks both of you..i finally got it..except that i have to add it the normal way like in my original qns then add it again like how Peter has suggested while also removing the old node like Jay suggested